# Como ocultar referencia de enlace a otra página

Tags: javascript, html

me explico:

Si tengo un sitio web www.abc.com y en el sitio tengo una url que lleva a www.xyz.com, como debo construir el enlace para que cuando el webmaster de xyz chequee su analytics o cualquiera que sea su programa de seguimiento no vea que hay un enlace en mi web y personas que están entrando a la suya por medio de él?

Preferiblemente que parezca que la url fue escrita directamente en la barra del navegador.

Perdón si pregunté una burrada, soy novato :)

Comment: Bienvenido al mundo de la informatica, pero por favor muestranos un poco mas de tu codigo, lo que ensayaste

Comment: explicanos mejor tu pregunta, por lo que veo tu problema no es de programacion

Comment: como podria saber eso? si haces un enlace directo es lo mismo que escribirlo en la barra del navegador. Opino igual que tus compañeros, explica mejor el problema...

Comment: No es posible a menos que tengas tu pagina tras un HTTPS y la referencia a la que te vas sea simple HTTP [HTTP Referer](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Referer)